# SwiftUI Button clicks when one element behind another

Tags: swiftui

I have a text and some boxes which are in a ScrollView. All of them are clickable `Button`.

The problem:

- when I click on "BUTTON" in the left image I get console log "text click". (All good)
- however, if I scroll down a bit and click "BUTTON" on the second image it actually clicks the box behind and I get console log "box click".

For some reason I end up clicking on the view behind instead of view in front. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

[image: image problem]

Here is the code reproducing the error. I am using Xcode 12.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!").font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.bottom, 150)
            
            HStack{
                Button(action: { print("text click") }) {
                    Text("TEXT")
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {

                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                        Button( action: {print("box click")}) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add clipping to your ScrollView, like

```
ScrollView {
   // ... other content here
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.clipped()
```